# Magento Password Lock Frontend?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I would like to create a Magento test website and put a Front page password, essentially to see the frontend you have to log in. To prevent everyone other than developers from accessing the site.

Any help ?

Comment: you can do that by filter ip. allow website to open to your ip only

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apache, then a `.htpasswd` file is what you're looking for, and an update to your `.htaccess`.

Use something like http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ to help you generate the `.htpasswd` file (the password is encrypted).  Create the file outside of the location you want to protect.  Then update your `.htaccess` file with:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```